# TFS won't recognise need to perform merge

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

A colleague and I are working on the same area of code using Visual Studio 2008 and TFS 2005 on the server.

When we both edit the same file concurrently and I check it in first, TFS does not recognise this when he either gets latest version or checks in, meaning his or my changes get overwritten without a painstaking manual merge.

This only seems to be a problem for him.

Any ideas what the problem might be or how we can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We removed and recreated the workspace and that fixed it.  Job done.

Comment: You could also have used the 'Force get' option. This way, you don't have to recreate the workspace.

Comment: We tried this, it didn't work.  TFS' knickers were in a severe twist I think.